# Autofac - SingleInstance get's instantiated for every API request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I'm working on an ASP.NET (not Core, but based on .NET Framework) WebAPI project. It uses Autofac for DI. I need to implement a Singleton/SingleInstance via Autofac. But the class gets instantiated for every API request. What I want is an object that exists for the entire runtime of the application and is always the same. Independent of any API request.
The controller requests the object in the constructor and Autofac properly delivers an instance of the object, but it's always a new one.
The only exception was, when I started the SingleInstance with AutoActivate it was created, then the *first* request got the same instance, but every following one received a new instance.
I use the current Autofac version 7.x and OWIN.

The class in question is named `ScriptExecutionHost`. It requests only a string as a parameter and two other singletons.  See below for details.

Here is the relevant code:

*Startup.cs*

```cs
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            var container = ContainerConfig.Configure();
            var config = GetHttpConfiguration(container);

            app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
            app.UseAutofacLifetimeScopeInjector(container);
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            ConfigureOAuth(app);

#if TESTSYSTEM || DEBUG
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            SwaggerConfig.Register(config);
#endif

            var physicalFileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem("./app");
            // Make ./app the default root of the static files in our Web Application.
            app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
            {
                RequestPath = new PathString(string.Empty),
                EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true,
                EnableDefaultFiles = true,
                FileSystem = physicalFileSystem,
                StaticFileOptions = { FileSystem = physicalFileSystem, ServeUnknownFileTypes = true },
                DefaultFilesOptions = { DefaultFileNames = new[] { "index.html" } }
            });

            app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.MapHandler);

            app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }

        private static HttpConfiguration GetHttpConfiguration(IContainer container)
        {
            // Create HttpConfiguration instance
            var config = new HttpConfiguration
            {
                DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container)
            };
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

            // tell the application to treat dates as UTC
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling =
                DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
                ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "DefaultApi",
                "api/{controller}/{id}",
                new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            return config;
        }

        private static void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider()
            };

            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        }
```

*ContainerConfig.Configure()*

```cs
        public static IContainer Configure()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // Register your Web API controllers.
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            // Register Credentials Service
            builder.Register(_ => new CredentialsService(CredentialManagerConfiguration.LoadFromWebConfig()))
                .As<CredentialsService>().SingleInstance();

            // Register our DatabaseContext
            builder.RegisterType<DatabaseContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();

            // Register the CredentialManagerConfiguration using the web.config
            builder.Register(_ => CredentialManagerConfiguration.LoadFromWebConfig()).AsSelf().SingleInstance();
            // Register the EmailConfiguration using the web.config
            builder.Register(_ => EmailConfiguration.LoadFromWebConfig()).AsSelf().SingleInstance();

            // Register the EmailClient using the EmailConfiguration from the web.config
            builder.RegisterType<EmailRepo>().As<IEmailRepo>().SingleInstance();

            // Register the UnitOfWork using the DatabaseContext, FileTemplates and EmailClient
            builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().AsSelf()
                .WithParameter("templateFileFolder", _fileTemplateBaseDirectory)
                .WithParameter("downloadDir", _fileDownloadBaseDirectory)
                .InstancePerRequest();

            builder.RegisterType<ScriptExecutionHost>().AsSelf().WithParameter("fileDownloadBaseDirectory", _fileDownloadBaseDirectory).SingleInstance().AutoActivate();

            // OPTIONAL: Register the Autofac model binder provider.
            builder.RegisterWebApiModelBinderProvider();

            return builder.Build();
        }
```

*The relevant controllers constructor*

```cs
        public ScriptsController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ScriptExecutionHost scriptExecutionHost) : base(unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _adService = new ActiveDirectoryService(new ActiveDirectoryConfiguration());
            _scripExecutionHost = scriptExecutionHost;
        }
```

*The ScriptExecutionHost constructor*

```cs
 public class ScriptExecutionHost : IRegisteredObject
    {
...
       public ScriptExecutionHost(string fileDownloadBaseDirectory, CredentialManagerConfiguration credentialManagerConfiguration, IEmailRepo emailRepo)
        {
            // Register ourself to the hosting environment to be able to shut down gracefully
            // This is necessary to ensure we can finish our work before the application pool is recycled
            HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this);

            _fileDownloadBaseDirectory = fileDownloadBaseDirectory;
            _credentialManagerConfiguration = credentialManagerConfiguration;
            _emailRepo = emailRepo;

            _logger.Debug("ScriptExecutionHost initialized.");
            _logger.Debug("File download base directory: {0}", _fileDownloadBaseDirectory);

// I used this to check if Autofac truly creates a new instance of this class every time.
            initTime = DateTime.Now;
        }
```

Comment: I can't necessarily answer this, but I do note you're using OWIN and I see `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` in there. OWIN does not use that. You can't mix the two - in OWIN you create the configuration, there is no GlobalConfiguration. If there is mix and match, that could be contributing to the problems.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I fixed that now and will update. Code excerpts. Nevertheless, the issue persists.